# Find first wildcard/expression that matches given value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

### What I need

I have two Google Sheets tables. I want to find the first cell of table 1 (which contain wildcards) that matches against my value in table 2. Then, take the value in the next column of the matching expression-cell and put it in the second column of table 2.

### Example

As an example, given the table below:

[image: Example Table]

Here is the CSV data:

```
Job Wildcards,Salary,,Job Description,Salary
*Dev*,40000,,Junior Developer,40000
*Engineer*,50000,,Senior Developer,40000
*Manager*,60000,,Platform Engineer,50000
,,,Project Manager,60000
,,,Team Manager,60000
```

The salaries in column E shall be auto-populated by looking for the first 'Job Wildcard' in the first table that matches the 'Job Description' and saving it's salary. I've provided the correct values manually.

---

### What I've tried

First I've thought about `vlookup`:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:$B5,2,FALSE)
```

But the error message confirms this does not work: `Did not find value 'Junior Developer' in VLOOKUP evaluation.`. Because I don't want to find 'Junior Developer', I wanna know what matches the other way around.

Then I've tried using index and match like this:

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$6,MATCH(D2,A$2:A$7,0))
```

But this returns a `#N/A` with kinda the same error as `vlookup`: `Did not find value 'Junior Developer' in MATCH evaluation.` which, again, makes sense. I still need to match column A against D and not D against A. But how do I do that?

Then I tried to use `REGEXMATCH`. For that, I've changed the wildcards to regular expressions (making `*` to `.*`):

```
=INDEX(FILTER(REGEXMATCH(A2,ARRAYFORMULA(D2:D7)), NOT(FALSE)), 1)
```

But here, I get the error `FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 7. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.`. And at this point, I admit defeat at this end.

I also replaced `*` with `%` and tried `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$D$6,"SELECT B where D like A")
```

But this also does not have the effect I was hoping for.

I think I'm close, but I would really appreciate a nudge into the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@ztiaa's and @rockinfreakshow's solutions were incorrect at like 5-20% of the time, depending on the regex-column sorting. As these formulas are quite complicated, I had no idea how to debug them.

I've found two other solutions.

## Solution 1: App Scripts function

Go to Extensions->Apps Script and add the following custom function:

```js
/**
 * Find the first cell of a range that matches against the given text and return a return value. 
 * @param {string} input The text to search for.
 * @param {range} input Two colums. The first must contain regular expressions to match against. The second must contain the corresponding return values.
 * @return The return value of the first regex match in the range that matches the given text. Returns 'NO_MATCH' on no match.
 * @customfunction
*/
function matchTextToRegexArray(cellText, regexResultsArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < regexResultsArray.length; i++) {
    var regex = new RegExp(regexResultsArray[i][0], "i");
    if (regex.test(cellText)) {
      return regexResultsArray[i][1];
    }
  }
  return "NO_MATCH";
}
```

Use it in the table as `=matchTextToRegexArray(D2,A$2:B)`.

This one is, for me, easy to understand. But it can be quite slow. Faster is solution 2

## Solution 2: QUERY

I've found the correct query:

```
=QUERY(A$3:$B$99, "select B where '"&lower(D2)&"' matches LOWER(A) limit 1")
```

Where:

- D2 is the search term
- Column A contains regular expressions (**you might need `.*` at the beginning and end of all terms in this column**)
- Column B contains the value you want to save alongside your search term

This is fast, easy and does not require any extras.

Thanks never the less!

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

**Using `Xmatch`**

```
=map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,
          array_constrain(torow(reduce(,sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;if(ifna(xmatch(index(A2:A,c),Σ,2)),index(B2:B,c),)})),1),1,1))))
```

this is ***case-insensitive***; `*Dev*` matches both `Junior Developer` and `Redevelopment`

---

**Using `Find`**

```
=map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,
          array_constrain(torow(reduce(,sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;if(iferror(find(index(substitute(A2:A,"*",""),c),Σ)),index(B2:B,c),)})),1),1,1))))
```

this is ***case-sensitive***; `*Dev*` matches ONLY `Junior Developer` and NOT `Redevelopment`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  BYROW(
   IF(ISERR(FIND(TOROW(SPLIT(A2:A,"*"),1),TOCOL(D2:D,1))),,
      TOROW(B2:B,1)),
   LAMBDA(x,IFNA(INDEX(x,XMATCH(,--(x="")))))))
```

This is case-sensitive, if you don't want it case-sensitive replace `FIND` with `SEARCH`.